# Multicasting in C: Binary does not receive when using addrinfo

Tags: c, sockets, multicast, multicastsocket

I have this funny little problem in two nearly identical programs. What I am trying to do is send some data on Multicast socket and receive it. For now, I am okay if the sender receives the message (I'll set the option to not receive later).

I have two implementation cases. In the first approach, I am using the traditional way of initializing a `sockaddr` structure and then binding to, and also joining a multicast group on the same socket. This, however, is IPv4/IPv6 dependent and to circumvent that, I tried to use `addrinfo` structures in the second variant of the program. Both programs are given below.

The problem is, the messages are being received in the first use case, where I am using the regular `sockaddr` while, there is no message being received/socket descriptor being set in the second case. Could somebody help me out and explain why is this happening?

### Variant 1 (with `sockaddr`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>       /* for nonblocking */
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

fd_set hm_tprt_conn_set;

main()
{
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    struct sockaddr_in mc_addr;
    int sock_fd ;
    int val;
    int reuse = 1;

    struct sockaddr_in ip;
    struct sockaddr_in src_addr;

    int total_bytes_rcvd=0;
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned char buf[50]; 
    int op_complete = 0;
    int os_error;

    struct timeval select_timeout;
    fd_set read_set;
    int32_t nready; //Number of ready descriptors

    time_t time_val;

    length = sizeof (src_addr);

    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sock_fd == -1)
    {
        printf("\n Error Opening UDP MCAST socket");
        perror("\n Cause is ");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("\n Setting the socket to non-blocking mode");
    val = fcntl(sock_fd, F_GETFL , 0);
    val = fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, val | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (val == -1)
    {
            printf("\n Error while setting socket to non-blocking mode");
            perror("Cause is ");
            sock_fd = -1;
            exit(0);
    } //end if val == -1

    if (setsockopt(sock_fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt: %d\n", errno);
        perror("Cause is ");
            exit(0);
    }

    FD_SET(sock_fd, &hm_tprt_conn_set);

    printf("\n Construct a mcast address structure");
    /* construct a multicast address structure */

    memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
    mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mc_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    mc_addr.sin_port = htons(4936);

    memset(&ip, 0, sizeof(ip));
    ip.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ip.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.203")/*htonl(INADDR_ANY)*/;
    ip.sin_port = htons(4936);

    printf("\n Bind the multicast address structure and port to the recieving socket ");
    if (bind( sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind: %d\n", errno);
            perror("\n Cause is ");
        exit(0);
     }

    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.203");
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        if(setsockopt(sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt: %d\n", errno);
        perror("\n Cause is ");
            exit(0);
    }

    printf("\nCreated Recv Socket: %d", sock_fd);   


    fflush(stdout);
    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
    while(1){
    /* Send a multicast */  
    time_val = time(NULL);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Hello: %s", ctime(&time_val));
        total_bytes_rcvd = sendto(sock_fd,
                        buf,
                        sizeof(buf),
                           0,
                          (struct sockaddr *)&ip,
                         length );
    printf("\n%d bytes sent.", total_bytes_rcvd);

    /* perform select */                         
        select_timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        select_timeout.tv_usec = 5000000;

        read_set = hm_tprt_conn_set;

        nready = select(sock_fd+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &select_timeout);
        if(nready == 0)
        {
            /***************************************************************************/
            /* No descriptors are ready                                                */
            /***************************************************************************/
            continue;
        }
        else if(nready == -1)
        {
            perror("Error Occurred on select() call.");
            continue;
        }

    if(FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &read_set))
        {
        printf("\n Recv the data"); 
        total_bytes_rcvd = recvfrom(sock_fd,
                                         buf,
                                      sizeof(buf),
                                       0,
                                  (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr,
                                     &length );

        printf("%s: message = \" %s \"\n", inet_ntoa(src_addr.sin_addr), buf);
        printf("\n total byte recieved %d", total_bytes_rcvd);

            /***************************************************************************/
            /* If select returned 1, and it was a listen socket, it makes sense to poll*/
            /* again by breaking out and use select again.                             */
            /***************************************************************************/
            if(--nready <=0)
            {
                printf("\nNo more incoming requests.");
                continue;
            }
        }//end select on listenfd
    }
}
```

### Variant 2 (with `addrinfo`)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>       /* for nonblocking */
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>      /* AI_PASSIVE and other Macros for getaddrinfo() */

fd_set hm_tprt_conn_set;

main()
{

  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *ressave;
  char target[128] = "127.0.0.1";
  char service[128] = "4936";

    struct ip_mreq mreq;

    int sock_fd ;
    int val;
    int reuse = 1;

    struct sockaddr_in ip;
    struct sockaddr_in src_addr;

    int total_bytes_rcvd=0;
    unsigned int length;
    unsigned char buf[50]; 
    int op_complete = 0;
    int os_error;

    struct timeval select_timeout;
    fd_set read_set;
    int32_t nready; //Number of ready descriptors

    time_t time_val;

    length = sizeof (src_addr);

  sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  if(sock_fd == -1)
  {
      printf("\n Error Opening UDP MCAST socket");
      perror("\n Cause is ");
      exit(0);
  }

  printf("\n Setting the socket to non-blocking mode");
  val = fcntl(sock_fd, F_GETFL , 0);
  val = fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, val | O_NONBLOCK);

  if (val == -1)
  {
          printf("\n Error while setting socket to non-blocking mode");
          perror("Cause is ");
          sock_fd = -1;
          exit(0);
  } //end if val == -1

  if (setsockopt(sock_fd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) == -1)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt: %d\n", errno);
        perror("Cause is ");
            exit(0);
    }

  FD_SET(sock_fd, &hm_tprt_conn_set);

    printf("\n Construct a mcast address structure");
    /* construct a multicast address structure */

  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

  if((os_error = getaddrinfo(target, service, &hints, &res)) !=0)
  {
      printf("\n%s",gai_strerror(os_error));
      exit(0);
  }

  ressave = res;

  if(bind(sock_fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error binding to port");
        close(sock_fd);
        sock_fd = -1;
    }

    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.203");
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(setsockopt(sock_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt: %d\n", errno);
        perror("Cause is ");
        exit(0);
    }

  /* Set Destination address */
    memset(&ip, 0, sizeof(ip));
    ip.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ip.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.203")/*htonl(INADDR_ANY)*/;
    ip.sin_port = htons(4936);

    /* Set to zero address where addresses of sender will be received */
    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));

    while(1){

    /* Send a multicast */  
    time_val = time(NULL);
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Hello: %s", ctime(&time_val));
        total_bytes_rcvd = sendto(sock_fd,
                        buf,
                        sizeof(buf),
                          0,
                          (struct sockaddr *)&ip,
                        length );

    printf("\n%d bytes sent.", total_bytes_rcvd);

    /* perform select */                         
        select_timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        select_timeout.tv_usec = 5000000;

        read_set = hm_tprt_conn_set;

        nready = select(sock_fd+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &select_timeout);
        if(nready == 0)
        {
            /***************************************************************************/
            /* No descriptors are ready                                                */
            /***************************************************************************/
            continue;
        }
        else if(nready == -1)
        {
            perror("Error Occurred on select() call.");
            continue;
        }

    if(FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &read_set))
        {
        printf("\n Recv the data"); 
        total_bytes_rcvd = recvfrom(sock_fd,
                                  buf,
                                  sizeof(buf),
                                    0,
                                  (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr,
                                  &length );

        printf("%s: message = \" %s \"\n", inet_ntoa(src_addr.sin_addr), buf);
        printf("\n total byte recieved %d", total_bytes_rcvd);

            /***************************************************************************/
            /* If select returned 1, and it was a listen socket, it makes sense to poll*/
            /* again by breaking out and use select again.                             */
            /***************************************************************************/
            if(--nready <=0)
            {
                printf("\nNo more incoming requests.");
                continue;
            }
        }//end select on listenfd
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in the first variant you're binding to INADDR_ANY, while in the second variant you're binding to 127.0.0.1.  Failing to bind to INADDR_ANY means you won't receive any multicast data.

You can fix this with the following:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE | AI_NUMERICSERV;

if((os_error = getaddrinfo(NULL, service, &hints, &res)) !=0)
{
   printf("\n%s",gai_strerror(os_error));
   exit(0);
}
```

From the man page for getaddrinfo regarding AI_PASSIVE:

> If  node  is NULL, the network address in each socket structure is initialized  according  to  the  AI_PASSIVE  flag,   which   is   set   in
>          hints.ai_flags.   The  network address in each socket structure will be
>          left unspecified if AI_PASSIVE flag is set.  This  is  used  by  server
>          applications,  which intend to accept client connections on any network
>          address.  The network address will be set  to  the  loopback  interface
>          address  if  the  AI_PASSIVE  flag  is not set.  This is used by client
>          applications, which intend to connect to a server running on  the  same
>          network host.

While in this case you are sending to the same host, multicast data does not go out on the localhost interface by default.  You would need to call `setsockopt` with the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` option to set the outgoing multicast interface.

With this change, I was able to send and receive with the second variant.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can `bind()` you need to have a working socket. You will need to cycle through all the results. Here's what's missing on your code.

```
ressave = res;

sock = socket(ressave->ai_family, ressave->ai_socktype, ressave->ai_protocol);
while(ressave != NULL && (sock < 0 || connect(sock, ressave->ai_addr, ressave->ai_addrlen) < 0)) {
    close(sock);
    if((ressave = ressave->ai_next) != NULL)
        sock = socket(ressave->ai_family, ressave->ai_socktype, ressave->ai_protocol);
}
```

At this point you have either found a working socket `sock` or not. When `ressave` is not NULL then the value of socket `sock` is valid.

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested, but even that is not helping. Also, in the main program, I do have a valid address returned in the first value itself, and the bind is also successful. That is, I do have a valid socket in the above program too.

Comment: Also, please note that I am talking about UDP Multicast sockets (unconnected). The same code logic works fine for TCP.